# I have a problem with this function "Uncaught ReferenceError: sync is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The function doesn't work, the console show me this message: Uncaught ReferenceError: sync is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/sfzc68w0/`
```

I expect the textarea will include the text from input

Comment: What you mean? What is `this function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because you have a function of the html event onkeyup

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label" for="i1">Adresa de email</label>
  <input type="text" id="i1" name="i1" value="" class="form-control input-sm"     

  [HERE===>]onkeyup="sync()">


  <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label" for="i2">Numarul de telefon</label>
  <input type="text" id="i2" name="i2" value="" class="form-control input-sm" 

  [HERE===>]onkeyup="sync()">

  <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label" for="i3">Județ</label>
  <input type="text" id="i3" name="i3" value="" class="form-control input-sm"     

  [HERE===>]onkeyup="sync()">

  <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-groenter code hereup col-md-12">
  <label for="body" class="label">Descriere - date de contact, adresă, stare etc.</label>
  <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
  <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

You have to remove it from there or just create the "sync()" function on the window object (on the window scope).

Comment: Reading deeply your JSFiddle i fund out that you are trying to set the value from the inputs into the textarea

Comment: Heres a new version that works (without the jquery syntax) https://jsfiddle.net/Lvqty1fw/1/